OAuth2 (Azure) clientSecret use?
We have a browser app(js single page app) with Azure oauth2 authentication, also connects to a backend server with rest api. Current implementation works like this:

front page has SSO Login button
browser app invokes https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=$appId&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=email%20openid%20profile%20offline_access&redirect_uri=https://appurl&code_challenge=..&.. to start an Azure login process.
(Azure specific redirects and web pages to choose an account)
Azure does a redirect back to an app https://appurl#code=ABC..&client_info=..&..
App does POST to https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token with a payload client_id=$appId&redirect_uri=https://appurl&code=ABC..&code_verifier=..&grant_type=authorization_code&..
Response has a json with access_token, id_token fields

App sends id_token value as-is to /rest/login backend.

token is verified in a backend signature key from azure, expiry, audience, issuer.
read sub,name,email,roles[] fields from the token.
creates an internal session identifier and return json to client js app.
client uses a session identifier in rest request as Authorization: Bearer xxAppSessionIdxx
at this point Azure id_token is forgotten as we know the user+role values.

Customer asked us where do we put a clientSecret value, it's available in an azure app registration page. We do not use it.
Question Should we use it and where? Trying to read docs it did not fully answer the question and some pages say clientSecret should not be used in SPA apps as the value is not really secret anymore in javascript browser apps.
Do we have less secure system at the moment? What should be done to make it better, like this?

client does the first oauth authorization request as of today
client sends #id_code=ABC.. value to a backend
backend does Azure /oauth2/v2.0/token request to transform "gibberish" code to id_token jwt value, today this happens in a client app.
creates an internal session identifier and return json to client js app.

Is there Azure app settings to force clientSecret usage so no one able to invoke /oauth2/v2.0/token without it? This value stays in a backend so it's hard to guess by just inspecting browser network tab.

Given that clientSecret is not required in this scenario, you may want to specify why your "client" wants to use it.

@GregAskew My understanding is they think it's an essential for the security. I would like to have a good understanding of the whole picture before answering anything.
